# Find path to optimal solution unboundeed knapsack

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need to find solution to the following problem:

> Maximize W = sum({n_k * v_k}) with respect to n_k, under the constraint W<=W_max

This is appears to be a variant of the unbounded knapsack problem. I have the following DP approach (written in C++):

```
auto findSize(int n_vals, int capacity, const int* values, int** mem)
    {
    if(n_vals == 0)
        {return 0;}
    if(capacity == 0)
        {return 0;}
    auto n = mem[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1];
    if(n != -1)
        {return n;}

    auto max_result = 0;
    auto k = 0;
    while(k*values[n_vals - 1] <= capacity)
        {
        auto val = k*values[n_vals - 1] + findSize(n_vals - 1, capacity - k*values[n_vals-1], values, mem);
        if(val > max_result)
            {max_result = val;}
        ++k;
        }
    mem[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1]=max_result;
    return max_result;
    }
```

I think I get the right answer, but I only get N. I also want the different n_k. How can I find these?

Answer (score 0):

In general, to record optimal path, you have to remember source coordinates (write them into additional storage array `prev`, parallel to `mem`) when choosing the best next step.

Perhaps something like this:

```
 if(val > max_result)
        {max_result = val;
         bestK = k}
...
mem[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1]=max_result;
prev[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1] = bestK;
```

Comment: And then find the highest values in mem which has a corresponding non-zero value in prev?

Comment: Then unwind path  back - last cell `prev[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1]` contains index of cell in previous row and so on

Comment: Or rather: the index is (capacity - 1) - values[n_vals - 1]*prev[n_vals - 1][capacity - 1]